# "Built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime" after installing Visual Studio 2019 for ASP.NET 3.5 Web Project

Tags: asp.net, .net, runtime-error, .net-3.5

I just got a new PC and after pulling down an existing .NET 3.5 SP1 web project, changing one line of C#, building and deploying I am getting the error below.  I was previously using Visual Studio 2017, but am using 2019 on my new PC.  I've checked my .NET versions on my projects in VS2019 and they have not changed, nor have the project or solution files.  Any idea why there's a difference in the runtime versions when publishing and deploying to the web server?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.Web.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyApp.Web.XmlSerializers' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes had the same issue and have resulted in re-creating the project and using the existing code files.

I've tried to update packages to the latest version, but this can sometimes be difficult since all the packages reference each other